# SQL Server to Snowflake Query Conversion

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to convert this query below to Snowflake but what I came up with kept giving me an error that it couldn't conver '04/17/22' to a numeric value.

SQL:

```sql
  SELECT  
  user_id AS u_id,  
  Substring(Max( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), system_modstamp, 121) +   
   CASE -- Categorizing all of the team roles  
   WHEN team_member_role LIKE 'AM%'   
    OR team_member_role LIKE '%AM %'   
    OR team_member_role LIKE 'ASR%'   
   THEN 'AM Sales'   
   WHEN team_member_role LIKE '%fsr%'   
   THEN 'FSR'   
   WHEN team_member_role LIKE '%RSD%'   
    AND team_member_role NOT LIKE '%parts%'   
   THEN 'AC Sales'   
   WHEN team_member_role LIKE 'RSA%'   
   THEN 'AC Sales'   
   ELSE team_member_role   
  END  
  ), 11, 99) AS team_groups, Max(system_modstamp) AS SYSTEM_MODSTAMP   
 FROM S_SFDC_ACCOUNT_TEAM   
 GROUP BY user_id
```

Snowflake:

```sql
SELECT  
  user_id AS u_id,  
  SUBSTR(Max( TO_VARCHAR( system_modstamp,'YYYY-MM-DD') + 
CASE WHEN team_member_role LIKE 'AM%' OR team_member_role LIKE '%AM %' OR team_member_role LIKE 'ASR%' THEN 'AM Sales' WHEN team_member_role LIKE '%fsr%' THEN 'FSR' WHEN team_member_role LIKE '%RSD%' AND team_member_role NOT LIKE '%parts%' THEN 'AC Sales' WHEN team_member_role LIKE 'RSA%' THEN 'AC Sales' ELSE team_member_role END 
), 11, 99) AS team_groups, Max(system_modstamp) AS SYSTEM_MODSTAMP 
FROM S_SFDC_ACCOUNT_TEAM   
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: What is datatype for system_modstap? Try changing ```TO_VARCHAR( system_modstamp,'YYYY-MM-DD')``` to ```TO_VARCHAR( system_modstamp::date,'YYYY-MM-DD')```

Comment: It should be a date field. I tried adding the ::date but I still got the same error.

"Numeric value '2022-04-24' is not recognized"

Comment: Also, use CONCAT function for doing concatenation and not ```+```.

Comment: In Snowflake, `+` tries to add numeric values.  It is not a way to concatenate strings.

Comment: Thank you Pankaj and Mike, not using the concat was my issue

Answer (score 1):

For closure, as expressed in the comments:

- The issue was using `+` for string concatenation, because in Snowflake you need to use `||` instead.

The error "couldn't convert '...' to a numeric value" shows that it tried to transform that date (into a string), and then Snowflake tried to convert it to a number for the `+` operation.

Thanks Pankaj and Mike!